# How to edit a featureService from ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, feature-service, arcgis-android

I've been trying to edit data in a FeatureService, hosted on my own ArcGIS Server (I'm not using ArcGIS Online).

I have created a map in my ArcGIS Server's Mobile Content Directory, using the following JSON:

```
{
    "version" : "1.1",
    "operationalLayers" : [{
            "url" : "http://example.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Bridges/FeatureServer/0",
            "visibility" : true,
            "opacity" : 0.75,
            "title" : "Bridges"
        }
    ],
    "baseMap" : {
        "baseMapLayers" : [{
                "url" : "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
            }
        ],
        "title" : "World Topographic Map"
    }
}
```

I've reached upto this point, by using [Dave Bouwman's Blog](http://blog.davebouwman.com/2010/07/12/add-your-own-map-services-to-arcgis-ios-apps/) and this [ESRI Documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/iphone/AppGuide/Maps.pdf).

I can add the map to the ArcGIS App on my Android Device. The data shows up, but the Edit tool (the little pencil Icon) does not show up.

Using [this](http://video.esri.com/watch/902/data-collection-and-editing-with-arcgis-for-smartphones) video from ESRI, I can get an editable map via ArcGIS online, but I want an editable map **without** ArcGIS Online.

Is it possible to edit a feature service directly, without using ArcGIS Online?

Comment: You've tagged this as `arcgis-10.0` but is that the precise version of ArcGIS for Server that you are using?

Comment: @PolyGeo: Yes we are still stuck on ArcGIS Server 10.0;

Answer (score 1):

The Linked pdf said

> ...the best way to understand the JSON format is to look at examples from ArcGIS Online

On searching for ArcGIS web map JSON format, I found that ESRI does have some limited documentation for this JSON format [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-web-map-json/index.html#/Web_map_format_overview/02qt00000007000000/).

Though the documentation itself is sparse, the samples are more than helpful. The relevant sample in my case was: [ArcGIS feature service operational layers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-web-map-json/index.html#/ArcGIS_feature_service_operational_layers/02qt00000017000000/).

If you look at the JSON, you will see that each featurelayer has a **popup**, as well at the entire object has a **widgets property**. This was the key to the whole problem.

I added these two things to my JSON Document, and republished in the Mobile Content Directory.

After this, I could view the attributes as well as edit the data in ArcGIS for Android.

My final JSON is something like this:

```
{
    "version" : "1.1",
    "operationalLayers" : [{
            "url" : "http://example.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Bridges/FeatureServer/0",
            "visibility" : true,
            "opacity" : 0.75,
            "title" : "Bridges",
            "mode" : 1,
            "id" : 1,
            "popupInfo" : {
                "title" : "Bridge Info",
                "fieldInfos" : [{
                        "fieldName" : "BLC",
                        "label" : "Name",
                        "isEditable" : true,
                        "tooltip" : "",
                        "visible" : true,
                        "format" : null,
                        "stringFieldOption" : "textbox"
                    }
                ],
                "description" : null,
                "showAttachments" : false,
                "mediaInfos" : []
            }
            ],
            "baseMap" : {
                "baseMapLayers" : [{
                        "url" : "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"
                    }
                ],
                "title" : "World Topographic Map"
            },
            "widgets" : {
                "editor" : {}
            }
        }
```